# How do I extract a substring after the final delimiter?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using Ruby, and I want to write a function that takes a delimited string `str` (delimited by `//`), and returns the final part of the string, that is, the part after the last `//` in the string. For example, given `a//b///cd`, it should return `cd`.

Can I use a regular expression to do this, and if so, what expression should I use?

Comment: This should work `/.*\/\/(.*)/`. You need to pick the 1st capturing group, though. http://rubular.com/r/k4Ow6WskY2

Comment: @nhahtdh why not just write a simple answer so the user could accept it ?

Comment: @oldergod: Feel free to take the comment and write one, since I don't know the language Ruby itself.

Comment: @nhahtdh str.match(/.*\/\/(.*)/)[1]

Comment: @halfelf: `str[%r{.*//(.*)}, 1]` might be nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nhahtdh wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355516/ruby-substring-after-last/13355618#comment18229710_13355516) you can use `/.*\/\/(.*)/`

Which in Ruby, would be something like

```
regex = %r{.*               # any character (0 up to infinit-times) till we find the last
           //               # two consecutive characters '/'
           (?<last_part>.*) # any character (0 up to infinit-times)
          }
string = 'a//b///cd'

puts regex.match(string)[:last_part]
#=> cd
```

You can find about the `%r` in the [`RegularExpression`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_stdtypes.html#S4) section of the `ProgrammingRuby`.